# Can I pause an ECS service instead of deleting it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Haven't been able to find this in docs. Can I just pause an ECS service so it stops creating new tasks? Or do I have to delete it to stop that behavior?

I just want to temporarily suspend it from creating new tasks on the cluster.

Comment: From what I recall, pausing continues to run background tasks and I had to dive deep into identifying, stopping/deleting the instances from spinning off other dependency services.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can accomplish a "pause" by adjusting your service configuration to match your current number of running tasks. For example, if you currently have 3 running tasks in your service, you'd configure the service as below:

[image: .]

This tells the service:

- *The number of tasks I want is `[current-count]`*
- *I want you to maintain **at least** `[current-count]`*
- *I don't want **more than** `[current-count`*

These combined effectively halt your service from making any changes.

Comment: ah yes, this makes sense. And i could set to 0 tasks to "turn off" the service. feel dumb for no coming to this conclusion myself

Comment: Don't feel bad, AWS is notoriously ambiguous in much of their UI

Answer (score 53):

It is enough to set the desired number of tasks for a service to 0.
ECS will automatically remove all running tasks.

```
aws ecs update-service --desired-count 0 --cluster "ecs-my-ClusterName" --service "service-my-ServiceName-117U7OHVC5NJP"
```

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is incorrect.
If you set both "Minimum healthy percent" and "Maximum healthy percent" to 100, AWS will give you an error similar to following:

[image]

To stop service from creating new tasks, you have to update service by updating task definition and setting desired number of tasks to 0. After that you can use AWS CLI (fastest option) to stop existing running tasks , for example:

```
aws ecs list-services --cluster "ecs-my-ClusterName"
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster "ecs-my-ClusterName" --service "service-my-ServiceName-117U7OHVC5NJP"
```

After that you will get the list of the running tasks for the service, such as:

```
 {
    "taskArns": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:task/12e13d93-1e75-4088-a7ab-08546d69dc2c",
        "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:task/35ed484a-cc8f-4b5f-8400-71e40a185806"
    ]
}
```

Finally use below to stop each task:

```
aws ecs stop-task --cluster "ecs-my-ClusterName" --task 12e13d93-1e75-4088-a7ab-08546d69dc2c
aws ecs stop-task --cluster "ecs-my-ClusterName" --task 35ed484a-cc8f-4b5f-8400-71e40a185806
```

**UPDATE:** *By setting the desired number of running tasks to 0, ECS will stop and drain all running tasks in that service. There is no need to stop them individually afterwards using CLI commands originally posted above.*

Comment: Thanks, looks like they updated what's allowed since I posted my original answer.

Comment: Update: setting desired number of running tasks to 0, will stop all running tasks in that service. No need to stop them individually afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

In case your ECS Service runs on a schedule and is managed by AWS Fargate, it is better to find the EventBridge Rule that Fargate defines for your service and disable it. That will effectively stop the service from launching tasks, as it won't be called by the EventBridge Rule.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).